# ontouchmove: Detecting the new element being touched when moving a touch across multiple elements

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, mobile-safari, dom-events

As far as I can tell, the event triggered by `ontouchmove` in mobile Safari only contains information about on which element the touch began. For example, let's assume I put my finger down on the element `.firstElement` and then drag it across the page until it is over `.secondElement`. I've inspected all the properties of the event object, but I can only seem to find references the `.firstElement`.

Is there a way to detect with `ontouchmove` which element the user's finger is currently touching?

Comment: Wouldn't that be eligible to the [drag & drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) API?

Comment: This is ios safari, not firefox.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be a duplicate of [How to find out the actual event.target of touchmove javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918842/how-to-find-out-the-actual-event-target-of-touchmove-javascript-event)

According to that answer, there is no data in the event object that references the element that the finger is currently over.  You can, however determine it with the following code:

```
var secondElement = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually just came across that solution myself! I'll award you the points though. And FWIW, I did search extensively on SO for an answer to it; I think SO's search engine could be improved...

Comment: I had to do:       var currentElement = document.elementFromPoint(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY);