# AngularJS touchmove event with multiple elements/scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile-safari, angularjs-directive

I am trying to handle a touchmove event for an ng-repeat'ed directive, regardless of where the touchstart occurred. In my present code, if one of the elements detects a touchstart, all touchmove events will be handled by that same element, regardless of where on the screen the touchmoves happen. When I execute similar functionality with a mousemove, each element correctly receives mousemove events only when the mouse is over the respective elements.

I have seen questions unrelated to AngularJS about detecting the DOM element for a touchmove event ([How to find out the actual event.target of touchmove javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918842/how-to-find-out-the-actual-event-target-of-touchmove-javascript-event)), but if I were to do that, I don't see a way of handling that inside a directive/controller with the correct scope.

Here is a basic example (for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/zMKKv/1/) to compare the difference in behavior between mousemove and touchmove:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="countController">
            <counter ng-repeat="item in somedata" />
        </div>
    </body>

</html>

//-----------

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: solid;
  float: left;
}

//-----------

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("countController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.somedata = [{
        label: "One",
        count: 0
    }, {
        label: "Two",
        count: 0
    }, {
        label: "Three",
        count: 0
    }];

    $scope.increment = function(item) {
      item.count = item.count + 1;
      $scope.$digest();
    };
});

app.directive("counter", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div class="box">{{item.label}}<p>{{item.count}}</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.on('mousemove', function () {
                scope.increment(scope.item);
            });

            element.on('touchmove', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                scope.increment(scope.item);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: have found a solution for this issue ? i have the same problem! my email is ahmedkarmous28@gmail.com ! thx :)