# forwarding long touch to multiple targets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using javascript/jquery/jquerymobile/cordova in my application currently testing on Android.

I am trying to detect the movement of a touch in a screen into the multiple targets/buttons that there maybe in the screen.

In a desktop hoover: would just do what I want. However, it does not work in mobile platforms as it does in desktops.

In my problem I am looking to throw some 288 very small buttons and I want to receive an event for each target that is `touched`/`mouseover` along the journey of the finger in the screen ( 1 single `touchstart`-`touchmove`-`touchend`).  As I understand it as soon as a `touchstart` happens, that target is the only one receiving the event notification, no matter where the touch ends or what else is touched.

I could do it with canvas and calculate the distance to 288 points at each finger movement etc. But would be resource intensive, specifically for a task that a web browser excels. Hence I am looking to see how much can I delegate to the browser.

-- edited 
I found a possible answer in [How to find out the actual event.target of touchmove javascript event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918842/how-to-find-out-the-actual-event-target-of-touchmove-javascript-event)

I will be testing today. However, I am concerned by  Steven Lu comments on performance. Specially as in my case there is a significant number of object/points that I need to track.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add js/html. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry Omar, I do not follow you

Comment: I meant enrich your question with HTML and JS code used.

Comment: have a look at touchswipe -- http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/ -- it can record the touch position on the screen and fire up events. i never used it myself with JQM so i don't know much about the compatibility