# Hammer.js - event.target does not change while panning on Android

Tags: android, target, hammer.js, pan

I'm trying to get Hammer update the event.target element while using the "pan" event on mobile Android (so far only checked 4.2).

The problem is if I attach Hammer to the *ul* and pan along the *li* elements the event.target is returned correctly on desktop browsers (Chrome in particular - check the console), but mobile Android event.target is always the first one clicked.

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('fired up!');
        var myParent = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];

        var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myParent, {domEvents: true});

        mc.add( new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, threshold: 0 }) );            
        mc.on("pan", function(ev) {
                console.log(ev.target);
            });
    });
```

An example can be found here:

http://designingreen.net/tests/test-hammer.html (just check the source)

Am I doing something wrong or is it a matter of Hammer?

**Edit:** Apparently this is an issue in Android and "touchmove" event. A good workaround solution is availible here:

[How to find out the actual event.target of touchmove javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918842/how-to-find-out-the-actual-event-target-of-touchmove-javascript-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue in Android with "touchmove" event. A good workaround solution is availible here:

[How to find out the actual event.target of touchmove javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918842/how-to-find-out-the-actual-event-target-of-touchmove-javascript-event)