# Pointer-events: none doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, events, pointer-events

I'm working on custom drag and drop module to Vue and I found a problem. To override browser D&D (because I need) on pointer down I'm cloning div which I want to drag and then trigger pointermove (on this event, I'm setting X and Y on cloned div), when I fire pointer up, the value of this div is transferred to drag place. To target element under cloned(dragged) div on pointer up event, I used a css property pointer-events: none (on cloned div) and everything is fine on the desktop. On mobile, event targeting always dragged element.

There is console.log from triggered events:
[logged events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQttm.png)

Comment: Did you try `stopPropagation()` on the drag handler? It would also help to help you, if you'd provided some code.

Comment: Yes, i tried it. There is sample https://jsfiddle.net/tLv3wzb8/23/
Keep in mind, this is just not working 100% sample. Passing values in this sample is not important, i need to focus just on triggering events on mobile. Look in dev console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer to my question in another question:
[How to find out the actual event.target of touchmove javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918842/how-to-find-out-the-actual-event-target-of-touchmove-javascript-event)

We can target element under our event by

```js
document.elementFromPoint(
    e.clientX,
    e.clientY
);
```

Answer (score 9):

Modern mobile browsers use the 'touch-action' CSS property instead.
You can read all about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Just add `touch-action: none;` to the same element you added `pointer-events: none;` to.

Otherwise, depending on how you set up your vue component, you may need to listen for the 'touchstart' and 'touchend' events and cancel them:

```
<TargetElement>.addEventListener( 'touchstart', e => e.preventDefault )
```

Comment: Pointer events are obsolete; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/pointerdown_event

Comment: obsolete is specification, not event