# Adding zoom to pinch on a mobile web map app

Tags: javascript, web, mobile, zooming, pinchzoom

I am working on a procedurally generated map displayed through WebGL. The users can move using keyboard keys or with panning (useful on mobile but this works with a mouse too). They can zoom with their mouse wheel, unfortunately this doesn't work on mobile. On mobile I would like to allow them to zoom by "pinching". Currently, on safari ios, it performs a "native" zoom which is a bit buggy, and if you unzoom, it shows all your safari opened windows.
How could I disable these "native pinch zoom effects", and detect pinch events to zoom my map manually?
I tried using `ontouchmove` events but it is not easy to debug because I can't trigger that event on my computer, and I can't open the debug console to show my console.logs on my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a similar issue. Will post a full answer when I have it.

However, I can already answer part of your question related to disabling "native pinch zoom effects".

According to this thread: [Pointer-events: none doesn't work on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084929/pointer-events-none-doesnt-work-on-mobile)

you should be using `touch-action: none;` on the dom element where pinching happens.

Comment: Hey thank you, here is the code I ended up using if this can help you: https://github.com/Th0rgal/eykar.org