# Pointermove event not returning element index on touch

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pointer-events

I'm trying to let users change some dot colours on a d3.js SVG chart.

It seems current element index is not being updated continuously in the `pointermove` event function *on touch* while for example cursor coordinates are.

I've used `touch-action` on the chart as advised elsewhere. I've tried many different options but none seem to work and I've run out of ideas.

The only thing I'm uncertain of is how I'm updating the function — maybe there's some proper way to do it?

I'm testing on iOS Safari.

```js
let col = "#000000";

const num = 60;

let LEDs = Array(num).fill(col);

const index = d3.local();

const width = 600;
const height = 600;
const r = Math.min(width, height) / 2.5;
const cr = (r * Math.PI) / num - 4;

const pie = d3.pie().value(1);
const arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(r * 2);

const svg = d3.create("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');

const touchGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`)
  .attr("id", "touch-group");
const circleGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`)
  .attr("id", "circle-group");

// LEDs
function updateLEDs() {
  touchGroup.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(LEDs))
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .each(function(d, i) {
      index.set(this, i);
    })
    .on("touchstart", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    })
    .on("pointermove", touched);

  const circleNodes = circleGroup
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(LEDs)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("fill", d => d)
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => r * Math.cos((2 * Math.PI * i) / num - Math.PI / 2))
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => r * Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * i) / num - Math.PI / 2))
    .attr("r", cr);

  function touched(event, d) {
    const i = d3.select(this).datum().index;
    let j = index.get(this);
    const a = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
    const p = event.pointerType;
    if (event.buttons === 1) {
      d3.select("#info").text("LED " + i + "/" + j + ", " + p + " @" + a);
      LEDs[index.get(this)] = `#${Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}`;
      circleNodes.data(LEDs);
      updateLEDs();
    }
  }
}

// Init
clock.append(svg.node());
updateLEDs();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#info {
  background: #222;
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  padding: 0.4em;
}

#clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
  touch-action: none;
  #touch-group {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  #circle-group {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<div id="info">LED</div>
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you are asking.  As I move my pointer around I can see it finding the "correct" index of each hidden pie slice.

Comment: @Mark can you try with touch as in on a mobile device? On iPhone/Safari, only a single initial element is updated, unlike with a mouse.

Comment: I see.  So what is your end goal for touch vs mouse?  For mouse, it updates color on move but only if the left button is mouse-down?  For touch, it updates color on touch-move?

Comment: Yes. I've actually just found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64883428/1421380. Seems there's some kind of performance saving thing. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64883428/1421380) and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4405541/1421380), it looks like the reason is a performance compromise on mobile and the solution that works is using the following to update the element index:

`document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)`

and in context of D3 an my example it would be:

`d3.select(document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)).datum().index;`

```js
let col = "#000000";
const num = 60;
let LEDs = Array(num).fill(col);

const width = 600;
const height = 600;
const r = Math.min(width, height) / 2.5;
const cr = (r * Math.PI) / num - 4;

const pie = d3.pie().value(1);
const arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(r * 2);

const svg = d3.create("svg")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMidYMid meet');
const touchGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`)
  .attr("id", "touch-group");
const circleGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`)
  .attr("id", "circle-group");

// LEDs
function updateLEDs() {
  touchGroup.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(LEDs))
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .on("touchstart", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    })
    .on("pointermove", touched);

  const circleNodes = circleGroup
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(LEDs)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("fill", d => d)
    .attr("cx", (d, i) => r * Math.cos((2 * Math.PI * i) / num - Math.PI / 2))
    .attr("cy", (d, i) => r * Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * i) / num - Math.PI / 2))
    .attr("r", cr);

  function touched(event, d) {
    const i = d3.select(document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)).datum().index;
    const a = [event.clientX, event.clientY];
    const p = event.pointerType;
    if (event.buttons === 1) {
      d3.select("#info").text("LED " + i + ", " + p + " @" + a);
      LEDs[i] = `#${Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}`;
      updateLEDs();
    }
  }
}

// Init
clock.append(svg.node());
updateLEDs();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#info {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  padding: 0.4em;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
  touch-action: none;
  #touch-group {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  #circle-group {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<div id="info">LED</div>
<div id="clock"></div>
```