When using stylus, pointermove event does not update target upon entering child
In the snippet below, the circle disappears if either (1) I click inside the circle and move the mouse or (2) I click outside the circle and move the cursor into the circle while holding down the mouse button.
But when I use a pen/stylus, only (1) works. If I try doing (2), by holding the pen down on the screen and moving it into the circle, nothing happens. In this case, e.target is still the element where the pen was first pressed down.
Is there a way to change this behavior and have the pen treated in the same way as the mouse? I would like to use this in a whiteboard app, where an eraser tool should remove elements it touches as it is dragged across the whiteboard.
(I'm using Google Chrome on a Microsoft Surface Pro running Windows 10. Edit: Microsoft Edge and iPhone Safari both behave in the same way.)


function moveHandler(e){
  if(e.buttons == 0) return;
  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "circle") e.target.remove();
}
svg {
  width: 100px;
  touch-action: none;
  background: green;
}
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" onpointermove="moveHandler(event)">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="25" fill="blue"/>
</svg>




And the touchmove Event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchmove_event

And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918842/how-to-find-out-the-actual-event-target-of-touchmove-javascript-event

From your description it sounds like the pen actually causes the pointer event to fire. Then you can try with other pointerevents. Try if pointerenter is fired when is enters the circle (and then test if the pointer is down).

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman If I replace onpointermove by ontouchmove , it behaves in the same way when using the stylus, but using the mouse no longer does anything.

@chrwahl With <circle onpointerenter="…"> the event fires when the pen enters the circle while hovering above the screen, but not when being pressed. With the mouse it fires in either case.

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks. It works correctly when e.target is changed to document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY), as in the answer you linked to. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll mark it as correct.
